# How to remove comma from TextField in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFormattedTextField with the Name Hectare. The double type value is declared as shown below

```
         String cultivationSize = JFormattedTextField3.getText();
         double hectare = Double.parseDouble(cultivationSize);
```

Now the problem is that when i enter more than 3 digits, by default the comma is entered after 3 digits, e.g. 1,000. I have to add this value to some other value. But, due to this comma,I am unable to do it.

How can I remove comma and add this value to some other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `string.replace(",","");`

i.e. your code should look like -

```
double hectare = Double.parseDouble(cultivationSize.replaceAll(",",""));
```

Comment: You are relying on a specific default locale. There are different grouping-symbols for different locales (e.g. "." for Germany, " " for France). The other solutions are all independent of the locale.

Answer (score 12):

Call the [getValue()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue%28%29) instead of `getText()` on JFormattedTextField

Answer (score 8):

A much easier solution

```
Format format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
format.setGroupingUsed(false);
JFormattedTextField jtf = new JFormattedTextField(format);
```

This will remove the grouping of the numbers using comma.

Answer (score 1):

You should use MaskFormater like this:

```
zipField = new JFormattedTextField(
                    createFormatter("#####"));
...
protected MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
    MaskFormatter formatter = null;
    try {
        formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
        System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return formatter;
}
```