# Get user input in a JFrame Java file before main program starts

Tags: java, jframe, user-input

I will need to do various test runs with the KDTreeTester.java file attached below. It'd be pretty inefficient to change the values (w, h, n, x) every time I finish a run and recompile the file.

That's when I thought it would be pretty handy to just type the values before the main program opens.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Main program that starts the KDTree visualization
 */
 public class KDTreeTester extends JFrame{

  int w=400;    //width of the window
  int h=400;    //height of the window
  int n=20;     //number of points
  int x=5;      //number of points to be searched (has to be smaller than n)
  KDTreeVisualization vis;  //the visualization

  public KDTreeTester(){

    //  Initialize the visualization and add it to the main frame. 
    vis = new KDTreeVisualization(w, h, n);
    add(vis);
```

The code goes on, but I think only that's the relevant part.
I need to have a box asking for the four values (width, height, number of points, number of points to be searched). The would have to be parsed from String to int I guess.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: you cant do anything before the main method starts, only if you start via cmd. you can use a custom JDialog

Comment: If you are using `JFrame`, then why not use `JTextField` to collect your inputs?

Answer (score 0):

As @XtremeBaumer told you :

> you cant do anything before the main method starts, only if you start
>   via cmd

However, if you mean ask for input values before your main frame is displayed, you may use `JOptionPane` to collect the values.

Here is an example based on [Multiple input in JOptionPane.showInputDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog) and, to limit the format to `integer` type, on [How to make JFormattedTextField accept integer without decimal point (comma)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467858/how-to-make-jformattedtextfield-accept-integer-without-decimal-point-comma)

Just call this before instantiating your `KDTreeVisualization`, and call it with those input parameters once you have them.

I wouldn't call this from the constructor of your `JFrame` though, but rather before instantiating the `JFrame`, or even through a custom menu/button/whatever you may add to your frame.

```
NumberFormat integerFieldFormatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();

JFormattedTextField nField = new JFormattedTextField(integerFieldFormatter);
JFormattedTextField xField = new JFormattedTextField(integerFieldFormatter);
JFormattedTextField widthField = new JFormattedTextField(integerFieldFormatter);
JFormattedTextField heightField = new JFormattedTextField(integerFieldFormatter);

Object[] message = {

        "Width :", widthField,
        "Height :", heightField,
        "n :", nField,
        "x :", xField
};

int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Enter values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

    try {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(nField.getText());
        int x = Integer.parseInt(xField.getText());
        int width = Integer.parseInt(xField.getText());
        int height = Integer.parseInt(xField.getText());

        // do stuff with the values, like instantitate your object with those parameters
        // new KDTreeVisualization(width, height, n)

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "At least one of the values is invalid", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

} else {
    System.out.println("Input cancelled");
}
```